# Operador "-" não pode ser aplicado à uma string

Tags: c#, string, operadores, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando fazer algumas alterações em um código pronto, porém eu me deparei com um problema com um linha de código escrita em C#:

```
string[] textArray1 = new string[] { -899253461.ToString() };
```

No caso, o Visual Studio me diz que o operador "-" não pode ser aplicado ao operando do tipo `string`. Gostaria de saber se isso é um problema de referência, pois a DLL do qual este código tem parte é totalmente funcional.

Comment: ```{ "-899253461".ToString() };```

Comment: @CypherPotato Se tá circundado com aspas não precisa usar o método `ToString`.

Answer (score 10):

O problema é de [precedência de operadores que tem sua tabela vista na documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). O [operador de negação numérica](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#unary-plus-and-minus-operators?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) tem uma precedência menor que o [operador de acesso a membros](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#member-access-operator-?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Aplicando a precedência o código pode ser lido assim:

```
var textArray1 = new string[] { -(899253461.ToString()) };
```

Quando na verdade você queria isto:

```
var textArray1 = new string[] { (-899253461).ToString() };
```

Então se escrever desta forma funciona.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/79LvTr). E no [**.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3gO5pN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/PrecedenceMinus.cs).

Isto faz mais sentido se usar uma variável:

```
var textArray1 = new string[] { (-numero).ToString() };
```

Se estiver realmente usando um literal não faz sentido usar esta forma de sintaxe, você pode usar uma *string direto:

```
var textArray1 = new string[] { "-899253461" };
```

Também é improvável que faz sentido ter um *array* aí, ele só tem um elemento e não pode ser expandido, então para que fazer isto? Se fosse só demonstrar o caso seria ok, mas está claro pelos comentários que o código está usado em contexto maior. Claro que existe algum caso onde isso faz sentido e ser passado como argumento de um método que espera um *array*, mas neste caso provavelmente só deveria criar o valor para o argumento e não uma variável.

Note que isto não é um problema do Visual Studio ou do compilador que se perde, é uma regra bem estabelecida pela linguagem e cumprida pelo compilador. O programador deve saber desta regra e aplicar o código necessário para mostrar melhor sua intenção, o que neste caso é aplicar os parenteses para o sinal ficar junto do número **antes** de fazer a conversão para `string`. Do jeito que escreveu o número normal é convertido para `string` e depois tenta-se aplicar o negativo neste texto, por isso dá o erro. E por isso não é necessário separar o número em outra linha, só colocar parenteses.

E C# não usa o conceitos de tipos primitivos.

Comment: Obrigado à você e a todos os outros pelas respostas, mas infelizmente nenhum método apresentado funcionou, não no sentido de que o VS considerou erro, mas sim na própria funcionalidade do .dll após a compilação, pois ele apresenta MISSING.STRING.VALUE exatamente aonde o elemento referente deveria ser apresentado. Eu já havia tentado algumas coisas anterior a minha pergunta, como algumas das respostas sugeriram, porém, todas me deram no mesmo erro após a compilação e execução da .dll.

Comment: Aí já é outro problema, o que foi respondido aqui foi o erro que você colocou na pergunta. Inclusive no código apresentado nem tem como dar outro tipo de erro. Para outro problema faça outra pergunta, está já foi respondida.

Comment: Exatamente por isso eu cometei se este seria um erro de referência, pois isso me pareceu ser mais um problema não relacionado ao código, visto que todas as respostas aqui apresentadas não funcionaram. Eu sei que o código original foi feito no VS, pois ele usa certos módulos que apenas existem no VS, e eu sei que está correto, pois eu verifiquei outras dlls semelhantes a esta que estou trabalhando, e todas, sem exceção, apresentam a mesma estrutura em suas strings.

Comment: A minha resposta funcionou e eu mostrei para você em duas IDEs *online*. Não tem erro de referência algum por seu código apresentado não tem nenhuma referência externa à linguagem, então não tem como dar esse erro. O erro que você está reportando agora é alguma coisa diferente de uma parte do código que não está na pergunta. No problema desta pergunta não tem nada a ver com DLL. Se você tem algum outro problema em outra parte do código que envolve DLL poste em uma nova pergunta. E seja claro na nova pergunta, aqui está sendo vago.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema sem alterar o código, bem simples na verdade, e de fato era uma referência que não constava na lista, e ele funcionou na forma que está apresentada. Bom vou tentar agradecer, pois de certa forma foi respondido, mas não acho que eu vou voltar mais aqui não.

Comment: Amigo, a comunidade infelizmente ainda é um pouco intolerante...
Mas... O forum é maravilhoso, recomendo tu voltar aqui sempre que tiver problemas... Afinal na maioria dos casos o problema é resolvido ;p


Quanto a minha resposta, já corrigi o que eu tinha respondido errado (No caso falando que o problema era do vs e não da linguagem)
E quando citei os tipos 'primitivos' repare que usei aspas (' ') justamente pq não são primitivos.

Comment: @MarccusZavadzki colocar algo errado entre aspas não torna algo correto. O que ele está falando nem é tipo por referência e sim referência à pacote externo, mas se fosse falar o oposto do tipo por referência sereia um tipo por valor e não um tipo primitivo já que uma *string* é um tipo por referência e é primitivo (onde este conceito é adotado). Agora o diz que o compilador se perde e ele não se perde, ele está adotando um regra estabelecida pela linguagem, conforme está na minha minha resposta. E ainda diz que a linguagem tem um problema e ela não tem. Note que nem falei do `int` porque...

Comment: ...neste caso até é verdade, mas um outro número poderia não ser um `int`, quando estamos tentando ensinar algo para a pessoa e não apenas resolver o problema da pessoa precisamos dizer como as coisas realmente são. E aqui não é um fórum, é um site de perguntas e respostas. Infelizmente muita gente não entende isto e não acham que a qualidade importa porque em fóruns a qualidade não costuma importar mesmo. Aqui é diferente, e as pessoas gostam porque tem mais qualidade do que se encontra por aí (pelo menos era assim, piorou muito ultimamente).

Comment: Isto só foi possível porque as pessoas são intolerantes com baixa qualidade, e fraudes de votação. Quem tem compromisso com o erro não gosta disto, muito típico no Brasil. Mas ainda tentamos, até cansar, e aí a qualidade se vai de vez e fica quase igual a um fórum e sai todo mundo dizendo que o SOpt já teve qualidade, vale pelo conteúdo antigo.

Answer (score 3):

Cara, erro de referência não é não, pelo fato dele estar usando tipos `'primitivos'`.

Acredito que o problema é que o compilador se perde nos sinais, ele primeiro converte o `inteiro` pra `string` e depois aplica o sinal, por isso o erro.

Se você usar um `()` pra primeiramente ele criar o `int` e depois converter pra `string` já resolve

Exemplo:

```
string[] textArray1 = new string[] { (-899253461).ToString() };
```